# How should I fetch the ThemeServices instance in Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have this code from a legacy Delphi 2010 application.

```
var InternalServices: TThemeServices;

function ThemeServices: TThemeServices;
begin
    if InternalServices = nil then
        InternalServices := ThemeServicesClass.Create;
    Result := InternalServices;
end;
```

The compiler tells me that ThemeServicesClass.Create does not exist. How should I do this in Delphi XE8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that you include in the question is lifted from the VCL's `Themes` unit. That code should not be compiled by you. It was probably always a mistake for your application to compile that code rather than using the code from the `Themes` unit.

In XE8 you should call the [`StyleServices`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Themes.StyleServices) method of `Vcl.Themes`. The name change (from `ThemeServices` to `StyleServices`) is to reflect that fact that the older XP theme support has now been augmented by VCL styles.

So far as I can ascertain, the code in your question should not be compiled by you. It should be removed. It may be part of a much greater piece of code that perhaps also performs dubious acts. Without full sight of that code it's not possible for us to give you definitive advice.

Comment: If far as i can see, it is used to execute this one line; DrawThemeBackground(ThemeServices.Theme[teHeader], Canvas.Handle, so i changed it to;
    DrawThemeBackground(StyleServices.Theme[teHeader], Canvas.Handle, and removed the code in the question. It now compiles.

Comment: `ThemeServices` still exists FWIW, but it is deprecated. So using `StyleServices` makes sense anyway.